# Can I apply configuration from puppet master to agent

Tags: puppet

I have following requirement.

1. I am running puppet to install and startup server in puppet agent and it works fine.
2. Then I am running some tests on that server ( I execute test from the machine where puppet master resides) . In those tests I want to shutdown the server running in the agent side.
3. Problem is I want to invoke this operation from master side to agent through puppet.

( As far as I know, normally we are triggering puppet from agent side to master and then master apply configurations to agent).

Can I do above described thing with puppet and how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out `puppet kick`

https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.6.2/man/kick.html

As the doc says, first you have to configure the agents in order to listen to `kick`

Comment: Puppet kick is deprecated in Puppet 3, and will be removed in Puppet 4. Consider using mcollective instead. Not only can mcollective trigger a puppet run, it can also stop and start a service directly.

Comment: can you provide a link where it says that ? The link I gave in my answer doesn't specify a deprecation!

Comment: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.7/reference/deprecated_command.html#puppet-kick

Comment: // , Why not just use Fabric or mcollective?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

https://github.com/alcCapone/doll

and give it a try! Very simple but helpful. Cheers.